# Google apps script - calculating with values from obejcts

Tags: arrays, object, google-apps-script, google-sheets

i converted a google sheets database into an array of objects using Apps scripts.
The Object consists of 4 values. {id: 1, value_1: 1, value_2: 2, value_3: 3}.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFnTC.jpg)

That´s the code:

```
function getDatabaseAsObjectArray() {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('database');
  const values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  const headers = values[0];
  const databaseAsObjectArray = [];

  for (let i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
    const entry = {};
    for (let j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
      const key = headers[j];
      if (key === '') continue;
      entry[key] = values[i][j];
    }
    databaseAsObjectArray.push(entry);
  }
  
}
```

Now, i am looking for a solution to calulate a 5th value (from value_2 and value_3) which are added to the object array after calculation:

Steps to be performed:
object array --> {id: 1, value_1: 1, value_2: 2, value_3: 3}

calculate new value: *value_4* = **value_2** + **value_3**

append value_4 to to the obeject array: {id: 1, value_1: 1, value_2: 2, value_3: 3, *value_4: 5*}

Has someone an idea to solve my problem. I am not familar in working with obejcts...

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Simple add the addition after the for loop as shown below:

```
function getDatabaseAsObjectArray() {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  const headers = values[0];
  const databaseAsObjectArray = [];

  for (let i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
    const entry = {};
    for (let j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
      const key = headers[j];
      if (key === '') continue;
      entry[key] = values[i][j];
    }
    entry.value_4 = entry.value_2+entry.value_3;
    databaseAsObjectArray.push(entry);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Hello TheWizEd, 
thanks for your post. I found a similar solution.

function getDatabaseAsObjectArray() {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  const headers = values[0];
  const databaseAsObjectArray = [];

  for (let i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
    const entry = {};
    for (let j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
      const key = headers[j];
      if (key === '') continue;
      entry[key] = values[i][j];
    }

    entry['value_4'] = entry['value_2'] + entry.´['value_3'] * 5 / 100;
    
    databaseAsObjectArray.push(entry);
  }
}
```

best regards